# Update all links in Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel file that contain a big list of information and one column is contain Links of file url in my hard disk. But the hard disk name change from F to G and all links are broken. Can  I update the links in easy way without the need to programming new application that complete this task.

[image: example]

Comment: You can work with macros. What type of excel file is it? (xls, xlsx, csv, ...)

Comment: I use xlsx in my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this VBA could work:

```
Sub HyperLinkChange()
   Dim oldtext As String
   Dim newtext As String
   Dim h As Hyperlink

   oldtext = "F:\"
   newtext = "G:\"
       For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
       x = InStr(1, h.Address, oldtext)
       If x > 0 Then
           h.Address = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
           Substitute(h.Address, oldtext, newtext)
       End If
       Next
End Sub
```